# Ordering a loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I've a bash script like this:

```
for d in /home/test/*
    do
    echo $d
done
```

Which ouputs this:

```
/home/test/newer dir
/home/test/oldest dir
```

I'd like to order the folders by creation time so that the 'oldest dir' directory appears first in the list. I've tried ls and tree variations to no avail.

For example,

```
for d in `ls -d -c -1 $PWD/*`
```

Returns:

```
/home/test/oldest
dir
/home/test/newer
dir
```

Very close, but it does not respect the space in the directory name. My question, how would I have oldest dir on top and support the whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -d -c $PWD/* | while read line
  do echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Technically a directory name could have a newline in it…

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's any way to do it in a shell script.

Comment: [There's a way](https://github.com/kojiromike/bash-sort/blob/master/sort) but it's too academic for a practical answer.

Comment: Here's an example of a practical solution to filenames containing newlines: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72924/4667 -- essentially, you use `\0` as a record separator instead of `\n` and take advantage of (usually GNU) tools that can handle the `\0` character (such as `sort -z`, `xargs -0`, `find ... -print0`).

Comment: Since no reasonable person would ever put a newline in a filename, I think we can be excused for not going to such extreme measures in most scripts. Spaces are bad enough, but they're not so hard to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique, kind of a Schwartzian transform:

```
stat -c $'%Z\t%n' /home/test/* | sort -n | cut -f2- |
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    # ...
```

This solution is fragile with filenames containing newlines.